# Is there a Python equivalent to PHP-FPM?

Tags: python, nginx, php

I'm starting a web project in Python and I'm looking for a process manager that offers reloading in the same manner as PHP-FPM.

I've built stuff with Python before and Paste seems similar to what I want, but not quite.

The need for the ability to reload the process rather than restart is to allow long-running tasks to complete uninterrupted where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about supervisor with uwsgi?

Comment: uwsgi 1.0 supports graceful reloading `uwsgi --reload <pidfile>`